# Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

What criteria should we be applying when deciding whether questions are off-topic? Is there any sort of rough consensus on this?

1. Why are SEO questions shut down as not programming related?
2. Is SEO a sysadmin or developer issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, there is SEO, and there is SEO.

One type of SEO is about good engineering practices to make the page more accessible and discoverable, which includes proper use of meta tags, good URL rewriting and stuff like that - these are fine.

And then there is the type of SEO that basically asks "How can I cheat Google's Page Rank?".

Of course, there is also a grey area of "How can I make my site display direct links to the Download or About section on Google?".

Really, I think the common-sense approach should apply here: If the question is about genuinely improving the site (which in almost all cases has Accessibility and Functionality improvements as a side effect), then I'm all for it, but if it's just for "ranking higher" (legitimate or not), then I'd vote against it.

Comment: Where would a question about proper meta tags be fine?

Comment: On SO, the criterion might be: is there an obvious, non-trivial programming issue connected to the SEO question.  A black-hat SEO question that threw up a really fascinating data structure would be OK then, I guess.

Answer (score 14):

The SEO tag is a bloody travesty.  It should probably be condemned, cordoned off and demolitioned.  It's rare that you'll find a question with one or more upvotes, and common to find them closed or downvoted.

Unfortunately, I don't see that happening without employee intervention.

Stack Overflow is a Q&A site about *programming questions*.  Questions about what constitutes good SEO, how to use SEO tools to improve rankings, etc aren't on topic.

The following are a few examples of **non**programming questions that relate to SEO found in the first six questions on the tag:

- How can I improve my Search Engine X's page rank?
- How do I do [something] using Search Engine X's webmaster tools?
- I could configure my website to do X or Y. Which is better for SEO?

The following **are** programming questions that relate to SEO found within the first two pages of SEO tagged questions (ugh):

- My SEO-friendly .htaccess rewrites aren't working because XYZ. why?
- My code for integrating my website with Search Engine X is broken...
- ... I give up, there are SO many awful questions in this tag ...

Comment: We cleaned [legal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal) and although this tag has more questions I don't see a reason why we couldn't do a similar handling of [seo] if we use the Roomba, delete and close votes / flags effectively.

Comment: I would say those two "seo questions" aren't seo questions. They are questions about the webserver (Apache) and the specific javascript/html code boilerplate.

Answer (score 10):

If you're ever in doubt about your SEO question being on or off-topic, understand that you can *generally* ask SEO questions on [Webmasters Stack Exchange](//webmasters.stackexchange.com). [Their FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has it listed first as a valid topic, but you should take a moment and familiarize yourself with what that community expects. As on Stack Overflow, they do not allow software/tool recommendations or site reviews/advice

> *Only could apply to your site* -- If the answers to your question could only apply to your site and not others, it's probably not a good fit for Webmasters. For example, questions such as "What am I doing wrong here?" or "Please review my site" are typically considered off-topic since they're unlikely to help future visitors to this site.

If you're still reading this, you probably still want to ask your question on Stack Overflow. Let's go over why we still have the SEO tag. SEO is still a topic here because people came to know url-rewriting as "SEO friendly URLs". For example

```
https://www.example.com/my-seo-friendly-url
```

Most web servers won't naturally serve that up because we're using under-the-hood tricks to make the web server work. We know it as [url-rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting), [url-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-routing) (many frameworks do that), [htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htaccess) (Apache was the first web server to do this), etc. As this is a type of programming, it is on-topic. We also use it as a semi-meta tag (where the tag doesn't describe the problem, but the usage, etc).

To put it another way, as long as your question is about programming, it's on-topic, even with the SEO tag.

The catch, of course, is what comprises "about programming"? Let's contrast two questions to help clarify what we mean

> I have this code here. Google didn't handle it correctly, which hurt my SEO, but I started digging around and found this problem in my code.
>
> > Some code here
>
> How can I fix it?

In this case, the question involves some code that has a direct problem. That SEO lead you to find the problem is irrelevant. But many off-topic code questions are more like this

> I have this code here. Google didn't handle it correctly, which hurt my SEO.
>
> > Some code here
>
> How can I make Google like this?

Notice the shift from fixing code to fixing SEO. If the code is broken, post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it's not often you'll be off-topic. But if the code is working, then you no longer have a coding problem, you have an SEO one. SEO is generally defined as the marketing of your website to search engines. They have tools and rules you need to abide by to rank well. Stack Overflow is not a site to ask questions about things like that. So if you need help with things like

- Your website not being indexed
- Questions about what type of code or page a search engine will crawl
  (i.e. does Google parse Javascript? [Answered on Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/does-the-google-spider-render-javascript))
- Your website not ranking well
- Your website not displaying correctly in a search engine's results (when it displays correctly for you, i.e. not reproducible)
- Can this code hurt my SEO?
- Any number of SEO tools that tell you you're not doing something right for SEO

then **your question is off-topic on Stack Overflow**. If you're thinking "I didn't see my question in that list", understand that it's not exhaustive.  You can still take a crack at asking here, but understand [there are many people who watch the tag to catch off-topic questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334707/provide-asking-instructions-for-seo). If someone has directed you to this question, it's a good sign it's off-topic, and possibly about to be closed as such. Again, if you're in doubt, try asking on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Perhaps a suggestion to ask on [meta.webmasters.se] would not be remiss? I'm not on that site, but we generally ask people, if they are truly doubtful, to ask on meta or chat...

Comment: @HereticMonkey In this case, no. The reason is that we don't need Meta WM to reiterate that SEO questions are on-topic. The Help Center covers that already. Now, not every SEO question might not be a good one to ask, but I don't think we should advise people to post a Meta in every case. In the event someone goes off-topic, the WM community can handle it.

Comment: I"m a moderator on Webmasters. One of our off-topic reasons is for questions that ask for individual help with a website such an SEO audit. If somebody were to ask why their website weren't getting indexed or not ranking well, we would close that question.  The extent of help we are willing to offer in such situations is our generic catch-all questions about those topics: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350) and [What are the best ways to improve a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2)

Comment: I also want to point out that questions asking for SEO tool recommendations are off-topic on Webmasters. We have many questions about how to use SEO tools, especially official tools like Google Search Console, but like on Stack Overflow, recommendation questions are off-topic.