# Provide asking instructions for SEO

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-tips

The SEO is a cesspool in the middle of a dumpster fire. Every day people ask new off topic questions with the tag.

The SEO tag attracts only the best minds who are sure to check if their questions are on topic prior to asking them.

[image]

No, sorry, I got that wrong.  It's full of idjits.  I see only one course of action—burn the tag, blacklist it, and murder anyone who attempts to use it in future.

But perhaps before we rain hellfire upon the masses struggling to get their website onto the main page of G$$gle, we can add an asking instruction?

A suggestion for what it says:

[image]

Comment: Maybe .. the wording ... nvm ... +1

Comment: Don't mind doing this, but... Kinda do need some better copy.

Comment: Now if only there were a way to make this the top result in searches for SEO...

Comment: @Shog9 oh I don't know. It has a kind of poetic beauty :)

Comment: But where else can I ask the Internet whether my choice of light mauve background will affect my seo?

Comment: wait is the tag off topic , i thought it was on topic since we have a SEO tag, facepalm PI

Comment: @ColdFire The tag is on topic for programming related SEO questions but a lot of them have nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Seeing this post kinda makes me think that not everyone is wrong when they say rep matters on meta when it comes to post reception..... Or is it just Will who can get away with this?

Comment: @Patrice [That's average post score on Meta, per K of reputation across all users](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/540587#graph). I guess it means rep doesn't matter that much... Would be interesting to query post score per number of red circles, though...

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75715/why-isnt-meta-funny-anymore @Patrice - if everyone does it, it gets annoying. So we have Will, who Won't get old.

Comment: @Patrice on meta, Will negotiated special privileges when he retired from mod duty. Down votes only count 0.25 of a vote :)

Comment: @Tunaki maybe, I actually bookmarked that to use it when someone makes that claim (thanks, it's useful). I may be wrong though, but I don't think a newer guy (or maybe ANYONE but Will... might just be Will), posting that kind of questions would get that reception. I was thinking rep at first... now I think it's just Will :D

Comment: @Will We(i)ll done, you cool sucker!

Comment: I'm upvoting to cheer this question as useful because it's about the SEO tag.

Comment: To complain about Will getting away with something like this is like complaining about Salvador Dalí getting away with [doing loads of drugs, being fascinated with Hitler to the point of obsession](http://listverse.com/2014/03/28/10-bizarre-facts-about-salvador-dali/), and [having a crazy sex life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Life_of_Salvador_Dal%C3%AD). You can complain about it; point out the fact that probably none of *us* would get away it. And you may even have a point, but most people will just shrug and say, "yeah, but he was *Salvador Dalí!*"

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Let's try something a bit more nuanced:

[image: WARNING! Only programming questions related to SEO are allowed here. For example, generating SEO-friendly markup for your single-page web app, or doing something crazy with .htaccess so that search engines don't hate you. For general questions on optimizing your site, try Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange instead. See also: Where to find answers to SEO questions?]

Comment: If I type SEO three times into a question will Will come out of my computer and slap me?

Comment: Well... I mean, he might do that anyway.

Comment: Can we get warnings like that for other tags?

Comment: Sure, @Nicol. Some already exist. Just be aware: they're not what I'd call *super* effective. Worth doing for particularly critical cases, but don't expect a majority of people to read 'em. Oh, and also the only UI that exists for these is essentially a table editor; keeping track of warnings is kinda stone-age.

Comment: Can we get one for the php tag where it asks if people has actually tried to debug their code?

Comment: I honestly think that link text looks ugly on the yellow background. I'd take the same white with underlines any time, but this...

Comment: The copy reads well enough, but something tells me you did not clear it with the Webmasters mods. :-)

Comment: Note that [SEO is the first item in their on-topic list](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), @Cody. Also, it's been linked to from the [tag:seo] wiki here for a long time.