# Should I be flagging incorrect "possible duplicate" comments as not constructive?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, comment-flags

Reviewing [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/2415822), I see this TL:DR (emphasis mine):

> TL;DR: Review carefully. Don't delete everything. Deletion is for things that actually aren't answers, *not* for low-quality answers or "wrong" answers. **Flag incorrect comments from review as "not constructive".**

Can this philosophy also be applied to incorrect comments about possible duplicates?

Reviewing duplicate questions, I will periodically see users incorrectly flag questions as duplicates:

**Exhibit A:** [Is Kerberos (GSS API) supported by iOS 5 or 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17887172/2415822)

Close Vote Comment:

> Possible duplicate of [SSH/Kerberos not working on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023126/ssh-kerberos-not-working-on-osx)

Opinion:

Not constructive (and incorrect), as the question is about iOS, not OS X.  While the linked question about OS X may contain useful information that may help solve the problem, the solutions may be different for each environment.

I flagged the comment as not constructive, the flag was declined.

**Exhibit B:** [How we know if our app uninstalled from iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13603774/2415822)

Close Flag Comment:

> Possible duplicate of [Tracking uninstall of android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888092/tracking-uninstall-of-android-app)

Opinion:

Also not constructive.  While on a high level app installations on iOS and Android may be similar, technically the process is very different.  I would strongly advise against closing this iOS question as a duplicate of the linked Android question.

I flagged the comment as not constructive and it was marked as helpful.

Should I be flagging incorrect duplicate auto-comments as not constructive?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that this is because you may need a little bit of domain knowledge to know if a duplicate is correct or not. Or, it might be that the mods want to leave those comments specifically because it _could_ help the OP, and they have no way of knowing if the OP has seen that post or not.

Comment: @Kendra I'm all for helping the OP, but it's also possible users will see the close vote or flag and also flag accordingly without actually realizing or knowing that the question is not a dupe.

Comment: Other users doing it wrong is not a reason, in my mind, to remove potentially helpful information. If users are dupe flagging incorrectly just because of one comment 1) That can be reversed and 2) the issue is those flaggers, not necessarily the comment.

Comment: Yeah I would also not flag suggested duplicates, since even if not 100% correct they can be constructive (NAA/VLQ review comments are different), I suggest you comment stating that it is not a duplicate because.., problem solved.

Comment: @JAL In addition to kendra's points, removing the comments wouldn't even stop people from doing that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This... seems like a bad idea.

1. Moderators don't necessarily know enough about the specific question to gauge whether the duplicate is accurate or not. And you're not including any explanation for *why* you think the duplicate is inappropriate in a "not constructive" flag.
2. Removing these links in cases where the question is related (even if not a duplicate) deprives other readers of potentially useful information and reduces curated cross-linking.

So unless the suggested duplicate is *blatantly* inappropriate (as in, somehow overtly insulting), I wouldn't flag them.

What you *can* do is reply to them. Not only does this provide useful feedback to the author of the comment, it allows other readers to quickly dismiss incorrect duplicate suggestions based on your rationale without having to retrace your steps themselves.

Comment: `And you're not including any explanation for why you think the duplicate is inappropriate in a "not constructive" flag.`  Well to be fair, there isn't really a way to add additional information to a comment flag unless I raised a custom flag, which I believe is inappropriate in this particular case.

Comment: Either way, this is a solid answer.  Thanks Shog.

Comment: "as in, somehow overtly insulting" Like creating a question titled "What is an SEO question and why do I have to [bugger right the hell off](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334707/provide-asking-instructions-for-seo) if I ask one?" and then closing SEO questions as a duplicate of it?

Comment: What I do is routinely use the 'other' comment flag reason, but start my remarks with the relevant other close reason (for example and most commonly 'obsolete'), and then explain why it is obsolete.  I don't get many such flags rejected.  I don't know whether the mods actually like that (anyone want to comment upon it?), but it seems to work.  I only use the simple push button close reasons when it is very blatant — I don't assume the mods understand the subject area.  However, that's not specifically for 'bad duplicates' — I just tend to counter-comment why I think the duplicate is bad.

Answer (score 8):

> Should I be flagging incorrect duplicate auto-comments as not constructive?

No. Determining whether or not a question is a duplicate requires some degree of domain knowledge and is thus *not* something that you should flag.

A "possible duplicate" comment doesn't *hurt* anything if it's wrong. It isn't "unconstructive", it's just factually incorrect and a link to irrelevant information, just as would be the case for any other technical comment. We don't flag those, either.

If you disagree with a duplicate proposal, then leave a counter-comment explaining your rationale. If you like, ping the user who left the original comment, since this will not only educate them for the future but may also motivate them to delete their original comment and perhaps revoke their close vote/flag. But even if you don't ping the original user, others will still see your comment and refrain from voting to close as a duplicate.

Flagging the other auto-generated "review" comments as "not constructive" is important, because they specifically encourage action. If that action is not appropriate, the comment is misleading and should be removed. That is not the case with a "possible duplicate" comment, since it can be harmlessly ignored. Besides, even if the question is not actually a duplicate, the proposed duplicate may still contain some vaguely relevant information.

Comment: Thanks Cody, I've already started replying to all comments (even before flagging).  I now see the differences between VLQ and dupe auto-comments.

Comment: FWIW, those auto-generated review comments are *supposed* to be automatically deleted every week if they haven't been acted on (or replied to)... Turns out, the task that does this has been failing for months, so I'm manually deleting 20 thousand or so of them right now, but hopefully that starts happening more reliably soon and there's less need to be flagging them.

Comment: @Shog9 that is a good idea if question is "Leave open", but if close votes age away as many do, maybe it's better leave them for future visitors. Hence "acted on" is not always true, the load of reviews are currently to heavy for the community

Comment: A residual duplicate comment from a failed attempt at closing can be very helpful/time-saving for when another person comes along and initiates the close vote process. Especially considering how much YMMV with the SO search functions.

Comment: I don't think @Shog9 meant that auto-generated "possible duplicate" comments should be automatically deleted, just the other "review" comments. But yeah, I agree that aged-away duplicate comments should *definitely* be kept.

Comment: I'm talking about the ones generated in review, @Petter - the ones Cody (and Undo) suggested flagging. Should be unnecessary most of the time.

Comment: ok, sorry, yeah commit!