# Declined Flag for Not Constructive comment

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I found the following comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009276/android-context-menu-cannot-refer-to-item-of-listview question:

> possible duplicate of How do I compare strings in Java? ... but still
>   **reputation's farmers** will answer this question

Then flagging it as `not constructive` but declined. I'm aware there are many users that answering just for the reputation, but I disagree calling them reputation farmer.

What is the correct response to the above comment? Should I flag it or just ignore it?

Comment: Despite what could be considered as a rude comment, it is still constructive because of the first half. I'd leave it; I know how he feels :/

Comment: @zondo: You've got a point, but I think he/she can put the explanation instead of sending the negative vibe.

Comment: Oh, I agree that the second half was unnecessary; I'm just saying that the comment as a whole is constructive because of the first half. And the second half isn't really all that bad. There are far worse comments to be flagging that happen every day.

Comment: Maybe this have worked if you had left your own, constructive version of the comment. The mod might have been OK with removing that one if the useful part about the duplicate wouldn't have been lost. That's just a guess though. They may have seen it as a warning to the OP that they were about to get stuck with a duplicate question since they can't delete after getting answers (or just one up voted one).

Comment: @BSMP: Editing the comment itself would have been an option, though.

Comment: @BoltClock - That's interesting. I don't think I knew that. I guess they just didn't think "reputation farmer" was particularly insulting (it's certainly better than what used to be the popular term).

Comment: So, how should we name these people now? Use a needlessly verbose who-phrase?

Comment: @BSMP @JanDvorak:  I'm sorry because that it looks like I send the wrong message in the question. What I really want to say is, the `but still reputation's farmers will answer this question` part is just a rant. Here the comment is `not constructive`

Comment: Now I'm a de-reputation farmer I guess..

Comment: I understood that you meant the whole phrase was unnecessary, I was just guessing at what the mod who handled the flag might have thought. Your question was clear. I think the comment from @JanDvorak might have been meant for me. Oh, and votes on Meta don't affect your reputation so don't worry about that.

Comment: @BSMP: `de-reputation farmer`, it just a sarcasm :P

Comment: I don't know why it was declined. I'd have removed the comment had I come across the flag, because a) it was long outdated and b) the second half is rather passive-aggressive and unnecessary. I have now removed the passive-aggressive part (the meta effect has attracted new dupe-close votes so the remainder has become relevant again).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tl;dr — Totally my mistake, the flag was correct. I'm really sorry for declining the flag.

---

Long story:

I had a small script that helps me process flags faster. It highlights the "Thank you" comments flagged as too chatty and "I edited it" comments flagged as obsolete. In this way, I can clear many flags in a few seconds. A few weeks back, [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343301/4099593) made it clear that we shouldn't be flagging "possible duplicate" comments as Not Constructive. I (foolishly) added "possible duplicate" when flagged as Not Constructive to the script. I realized today that this was a terrible mistake and  that I should not be using shortcuts.

[image]

I apologize again, I can't undecline a flag (nor dispute it). :-(

Comment: No problem at all. I'm really glad that we have a humble moderator. `A man must be big enough to admit his mistakes, smart enough to profit from them, and strong enough to correct them. John C. Maxwell`

Comment: Out of curiosity - How many flags have you handled since you became a mod?

Comment: @Kyll 51.5k flags, 135 days.

Comment: Well if that flag was your only error, that makes it a 99.998% hit ratio. Pretty nice.

Comment: This is my only mistake which was brought out publicly (and rightly, so that I can correct myself, thanks @ישואוהבאותך). I never know how many errors I have made which has passed off silently. :/