# Let's stop the [backlink]s

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[backlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backlink) (almost always used in conjunction with [everyone's favorite tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334707/provide-asking-instructions-for-seo) [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo))

There's no on-topic usage for this. Backlinks are an SEO metric that search engines use to measure a site's popularity ([hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyperlink), by contrast, is often on-topic). It has 0 bearing on any programming issues (getting other people to link to your site is not programming, it's marketing), and is strictly [a topic for Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backlinks)

44 questions (some are already closed). Could be short and sweet to burninate

Comment: As far as I'm concerned you are free to clean it, hit it hard!

Comment: [Only 13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backlink+seo) of the 42 questions use `backlink` with `seo`.

Comment: @4castle In most of the cases I've seen, people are mistagging this instead of [hyperlink]

Comment: What is your opinion of the usage of the tag on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817572/count-number-of-backlinks-to-a-domain)? Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23243720/5743988)?

Comment: Suggested title: "No link-backs"... wait, that doesn't work. Dangit.

Comment: @4castle I'd say remove the tag. The question is primarily about the Bing API and can stand on its own. Technically it's counting hyperlinks

Comment: @4castle the first is messy: OP said backlinks using Bing api, later added google to make, a now obsolete answer (the API returns 503), valid. I would say meh and just delete everything.

Comment: If someone could come up with a golf pun for the title, that'd be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roomba deleted the last closed question today. Many thanks to SOCVR in the cleanup effort.

Tag burninated!

Comment: YAY! \*sends psychological hugs all around\*