# How do we remove a Documentation tag?

Tags: support, documentation

So I noticed that SEO now has [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/seo/topics). It has [one topic with one example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/seo/8041/getting-started-with-seo/25972/installation-or-setup) that says this (literally)

> Installation or Setup
>
> Detailed instructions on getting seo set up or installed.

So let's count the problems here

1. SEO advice is off-topic for SO
2. Someone created a garbage entry
3. You can't delete the garbage because it's the only Example in the Topic
4. I pinged mods about this in chat and they kinda shrugged. There's no way that I can tell to flag this and mods may not even have the tools to deal with this

So how do we get rid of this junk?

Comment: Did you mean to write "How do we remove a Documentation tag?" in the title?

Comment: @dorukayhan Possibly. The terminology is confusing at points

Comment: Oh, boy. [Don't tell Will](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334707/provide-asking-instructions-for-seo).

Comment: SEO!  SLOWLY I TURNED.  STEP BY STEP...  INCH BY INCH...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We haven't spent much time thinking about removing Documentation from a tag because we're focused on helping folks contribute. So the "garbage entry" is the default topic and "example". It's purposely worthless as an example in order to invite proposed changes. Additionally, the Community creates a several improvement requests to guide users in the right direction. Clearly it didn't work in this case.

So the first step is to actually create a route to reset a tag to the stage where nobody has committed to it. Since I'm not a developer, I'll just assume it'll be easy to invalidate the commitments and remove the topic. (In the future, I suppose we should consider what we'd need to do when some proposed changes have been approved. But that's not the case we are looking at today.)

The essentially blank introductory topic isn't intended to be the anything like a final state for a tag. Over on Area 51, we've had a similar problem when people propose a new site and then don't start adding example questions. We have [a process](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/minimum-activity-requirements-for-area-51) that deletes these proposals after 3 days. That way there isn't an unsupported proposal blocking the progress of potentially more successful attempts. I mean, you *could* revive the moribund proposal, but it's a lot more exciting to be there for the start of the process. (This is true both of Area 51 and a tag's documentation.)

Once documentation can be removed manually, I propose an automated task to **remove documentation from tags if they have not had any proposed changes approved in the first**, let's say, **7 days**. That gives the committers plenty of time to write up an introductory topic. If all the proposed changes are rejected or rolled back, there aren't any proposed changes awaiting review, and the deadline has passed, it's safe to assume documentation isn't gaining traction for that particular tag.

(What happens to drafts that haven't been submitted when a tag's documentation is removed? Ideally they would be available in case the tag's documentation is created again. But I don't think it's very critical one way or another.)

We might also consider improving the standard Improvement Requests to give users a better idea of what they need to do. Currently, the initial IRs are a bit busy:

[image: Yikes! That's a lot of stuff to do!]

I think that's an example of [choice overload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overchoice). It might be better to have just one topic-level improvement request that says something like:

> Please fill in this topic with examples useful for someone just getting started in `$tagname`. Also update the Remarks section and, if applicable, the Version section. This tag's documentation will be be removed unless it has at least one approved proposed change by `$today+7`.

Although it is kind of nice to have several discrete tasks to do over time, having so many choices makes it hard to focus on the critical path.

Comment: I like it but I would suggest one other thing: a flag (maybe mod set?) that would turn the Docs banner off for some tags and prevent them from being added to Docs. As noted (jokingly) by Brad Larson, SEO is a contentious tag that produces a LOT of moderation work in general. If Docs go SE-wide I could see this fitting well on Webmasters.SE but it has no place here (the valid SEO Docs entries would be horribly shallow for the subject). I can easily think of other tags that would fall into this category as well ([gpl], [lgpl], [licensing], etc)

Comment: @Machavity: Moderators already have the power to make duplicate documentation tags (for things like versioned tags). So being able to make a tag undocumentable shouldn't be a large step from that.

Comment: It would be nice for moderators to have the ability to [kill bad tag proposals](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/navbar) by now...