# Is it true that I am not allowed to change my user name after one or two times?

Tags: discussion, support, display-names

I think I changed it once and then a second time **(but that was some 4, 5 years ago)**. And right now I cannot change it (I don't see the UI for changing it at all).

One thing I found was that if I use Chinese characters for my user name, it can irritate some users, as they may not know what it means, or not know what language it is, and not know whether the name is offensive or has offensive meaning, and they cannot pronounce it, or type it (some users will not go the copy and paste route if they don't know what those characters mean).

(But as time go by, seems like more users accepted it, but still on another StackExchange site, some users might seem they didn't like it, especially if my reputation on those sites are merely 500 or 600).

So I thought I might change it, except I didn't find any UI that supposedly should be there for me to change it. Is the UI hidden due to me changing it twice already?

Comment: hold on... I changed it the last time some 4, 5 years ago... (way more than 1 month)

Comment: Are users actually leaving comments complaining about your name? If so, flag those comments. They are Too Chatty at best though I would suspect some of them of being rude. (Also, you should edit that information about the last time you changed your name into your question.)

Comment: I think two users complained they don't know what the name means or they can't pronounce it. Some other times they may not say it, but just act irritated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current

Comment: It's not reasonable for anyone to expect that all usernames on the Internet to be pronounceable. You can change your name if you want (assuing ale's link works for you) but you aren't obligated to do so. This is their problem, not yours.

Comment: The only reason I would have reservations is that it is slightly more difficult for those of us with Latin keyboards to @ mention you (if you were not the post author). Certainly don't feel obliged to change it if you don't want to.

Comment: What @BSMP said. If somebody really does have a problem with your username they can flag it for moderator attention. And if they haven't bothered to translate it to see if it actually is offensive (spoiler: it's not), or they just want something to be mad about regardless, then joke's on them.

Comment: @BSMP thank you for so supportive BSMP. Sometimes they will just downvote me no matter I post a question or answer. Then it will become "MY" problem

Comment: Since you can't autocomplete @ on at least some mobile views (and copy-paste is not fun either) I find it  safe to assume user with such name is not interested in comments. This is fine by me, but I can see why some people may be against it (especially if such user makes comments that ask for some reply). May be just feature-request to correctly handle autocomplete on all views...

Comment: It took me all of 30 seconds to use Google-translate on the name. Personally, I rather like how international Stack Overflow is. On the other hand, @AlexeiLevenkov raises a good practical point about non-ascii names.

Comment: Just because YOU don't have the capability to type in a name, does not mean others don't.  Folks getting uppity about a name they can't type are casually racist at best, if not downright bigoted.  Comments suggesting such a user doesn't want to receive comments are in the same category.

Answer (score 13):

You're allowed to change your name within [these rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names)

> - only one display name change is allowed every 30 days
> - user accounts less than 2 days old may change their displayname at will
> - there is a 15 minute grace period after each change during which you may change your displayname at will

Mods, of course, can change your name at will (although only in certain circumstances)

You can edit your username [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current)

Comment: I did +1 since this does address the rules as asked, but since it seems the OP is having trouble finding the UI to edit the display name, it might be useful to edit in the process to update the display name

Comment: *Mods, of course, can change your name at will* - while we can - we won't unless it violates the be nice policy. "at will" sounds a little laissez faire.

Comment: @jonclements Edited for clarity

Comment: @Makyen [This might have something to do with it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334707/provide-asking-instructions-for-seo#comment396270_334713)