# How to deal with a user who pasted a whole different code as answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I just came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48490079/5861618) where the user provided his existing code as answer to a question where the OP had already provided the code that he had tried.

The answer's code is completely different from the OP's and it loads different resources that the OP doesn't have access to.

How to proceed in this case? Should the answer be flagged? Or a simple comment will do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's an attempt at an answer - the "try this it worked for me" is a giveaway - but it might be a poor answer.

**You do not flag poor answers.**. You downvote them.  I wouldn't recommend leaving a comment, but you could if you must.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've just found this [meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/5861618) which shows when to flag an answer.

Comment: IMHO downvoting without commenting is kind of poor form - how is the answerer supposed to know what they did wrong and improve?

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ:  My philosophy as pnuts alluded to is that I wish to avoid a shouting match about why they did or did not deserve a downvote.

Comment: Downvotes on answers are helpful to explain why one feels it's not the best approach. If the comments aren't leading to anything positive, one could delete them. But avoiding the possibility of a shouting match, which by the way, violates the Be Nice policy, is not going to be helpful, and could leave the answerer feeling lost and not valued, while we want them to understand that their answer needs improvement, not deletion.

Comment: I've been around here quite a while, can't recall ever being involved in any "shouting matches". Or is that what you call polite disagreement :)

Comment: Speaking of downvoting, I found [this project](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) that contains explanations to the most common downvotes. @SteveBennettㄹ

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes:  I'm acutely aware of that site.  I find little value in it; you can read my reaction to it [over here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355951/1079354).