# Should I flag a question/answer if I left a comment for the author?

Tags: support, review-queues

Suppose I'm reviewing and I come across a question that is missing an MVCE (for instance). It's either a very long piece of code with lots of irrelevant parts, or just an error message without code.

I'm assuming that leaving a comment encouraging the author to add an MCVE is a good idea. Not just a canned message with a link to the FAQ, but actual instructions (otherwise I'd just flag and move on).

So the question is: should I still flag it? I can argue both for yes or no. On the one hand, I usually assume the author will fail to comply; on the other hand, it makes little sense to mark as "unsalvageable" a question that could be salvaged.

Comment: Your second point is addressed by [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263/7795130), basically, if you comment you should still flag, because if they fix their post, then the question can be reopened.

Comment: Thanks. And I guess the question as a whole has been addressed here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions/276637#276637

Comment: As for the first point, it depends on the comment. As per [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356051/7795130), "Bare links (http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) come off as cold and unhelpful," so of course there are bad ways to say that they should add an MCVE, but there are also welcoming and helpful ways to request it too, so it depends on how you comment.

Comment: @Giusti Ah you're right, in the question you found it already covers all points thoroughly. We could probably close this one as a duplicate of that.

Comment: @yivi sorry, my intention was only the second question. But as I wrote it, it occurred to me that the question itself might be ill-posed if leaving the comment itself was wrong in the first place. I'll edit.

Comment: @DavyM I agree. It's a duplicate.

Comment: @giusti If you believe your own question is a duplicate, you can flag it as such, and it will be immediately closed as such. That saves us from wasting close votes.\

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Won't OP have to accept the duplicate after flagging? (after refreshing the page inbetween)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Oh, sorry. I thought it would be weird for me to flag my own question. But I'll keep that in mind from now on.