# How should bare idownvotedbecau.se links in comments be flagged?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags, welcoming

I just flagged a comment that simply consisted of several idownvotedbecau.se links and nothing else, something like:

> idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve* idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

It disappeared instantly, so presumably idownvotedbecau.se is one of the magic phrases that deletes comments immediately.

I hesitated between 'no longer needed' and 'unfriendly or unkind' - I seem to remember the welcome wagon specifically calling out idownvotedbecau.se as unfriendly, but couldn't quite convince myself that it was worthy of a telling off.

Is there a right answer here, or is it a matter of context?

*should I submit a pull request to add idownvotedbecau.se/nomin-reproex? :P

Comment: I wouldn't bet money on acceptance of such a PR :-)'

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355950/is-idownvotedbecau-se-recommended

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Community Manager Tim Post added an answer there on January 30th of this year. It's easy to miss, though, since it's at like -15 score currently, which is unfortunate, because it's quite on point and very correct.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I didn't scroll that far. Agree that it's a very reasonable point. As it happens I think the same user immediately posted another comment on the same question with just one idownvotedbecau.se link and nothing else, so I've just mod flagged that one anyway. Will remember for the future.

Comment: Tim Post even calls out that just leaving the link(s) is one of the things that could be considered using it in the wrong way.

Comment: I requested clarification on that comment thread.  Just a single link by itself isn't unfriendly.  Multiple, over a single or several comments is.

Comment: @fbueckert - I think I agree with you, at least that it's not clear that the _intent_ of the commenter is to be unfriendly. But when I try to put myself in the shoes of a new user, perhaps with a limited grasp of English, I can see how the wording of the link itself could be taken as a bit too direct. A wall of them as was the case here definitely isn't _friendly_, but I wasn't too sure whether it stretched to actively _unfriendly_. That said, I totally agree with your point in that comment thread that the root cause is SO not providing equivalent functionality on the platform.

Comment: There is certainly a point where multiple can feel like a dogpile and that'll definitely turn people away.  At the same time, those links can provide useful feedback to what is wrong with the post, and why it needs fixing.  It is absolutely more friendly to leave a comment with one of those link than just downvote and move on.  Balance is a tricky thing, but that needs to be judged on a case by case basis; there's no hard, "this many is too many" tipping point.

Comment: If you have to drop four links on a question, I'd submit there's no helping at that point.

Comment: Additional feature request: gold badger commenting with two or more of these links makes Community auto-close the question as the first one.

Comment: Few people like to be told their question is weak or bad. Fewer still are going to like being told that their post is weak or bad *and* banal enough to have its own web page.

Comment: FWIW, when I first started here and I was browsing questions (I never got one of these comments on anything I wrote), I didn't understand the idownvotedbecau.se links because they ended in `.se` (that was before the trend of domains ending in .biz, .io, .whatever, etc). I thought it was some kind of meme or something, I didn't realize they were real links, I thought they were just making up a link like `thisquestion.sucks` (don't go there, I don't know where it goes) and I wouldn't have clicked on them because of that.

Comment: @TylerH It's *not* unfortunate that that Meta post has an extremely negative score - I've read it several times and still have no clue what it's trying to say (beyond arguably being another [kick the dog](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KicktheDog) moment from SE directed at people who moderate the site).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

“No longer needed” is appropriate for this and most other general-purpose comment flagging. Comment flags mean “please delete this comment”, and “no longer needed” captures that message quite adequately.

As I’ve described elsewhere, I’m no big fan of these comments. They don’t help much, if at all. Despite it being a perennial feature request, experience tells us that the vast majority of people do *not* like being told why their question is being downvoted. At best, it’s just a jumping-off point for an argument.

Furthermore, most everything that you would use such a link to explain is adequately covered by a close reason, so once the question is closed, there’s no point whatsoever in having a link to an off-site resource that says the same thing as the big yellow banner underneath the question. This is another excellent use-case for “no longer needed” flags on such comments. The information is now conveyed in a more appropriate place.

On a tangential note, what is with people copying and pasting close reason descriptions into the comments? That’s just noise. Vote to close, and move on. Don’t give people more mess to clean up.

Comments that are not useful or have become obsolete should pretty much always be flagged as “no longer needed”. Please *don’t* flag comments that give specific, concrete advice on how to improve that particular question, regardless of whether they have links to idownvotedbecau.se or not. Those are the types of comments people *should* be leaving. They’re only obsolete when the problem has been clearly fixed.

While it may be true that certain folks are using these links as a “fork” (in the words of Tim Post), I’ve yet to be able to deduce that from a single comment, and when you’re flagging a single comment, you’re only flagging that comment to request its deletion. If you wish to point out that someone is repeatedly leaving unconstructive or even rude comments, please flag one of their posts instead, and describe the problem in detail. That will allow a moderator to assess the bigger picture and take an appropriate action.

Although I’m far from being an advocate of these sorts of link-only comments, I have a hard time imagining one that would really rise to the level of “unfriendly or unkind”. I don’t see any inherent Code of Conduct violation. I’d be inclined to dismiss such a flag but still delete the comment—a clear sign that “no longer needed” would have been a more appropriate choice.

If you disagree, or if you see a comment that really does rise to the level of “unfriendly or unkind” in your judgment, definitely feel free to flag it as such. Moderators do take all flags seriously, and will handle it as our judgment dictates.

Just don’t be surprised if it gets declined, and don’t expect it to catalyze an in-depth investigation into a user’s broader commenting patterns of behavior.

Comment: _"On a tangential note, what is with people copying and pasting close reason descriptions into the comments?"_ I don't usually do that (if ever, not _verbatim_ from the close reason), but there is some reasoning in giving the user that information without having to wait for the question to be closed, which could take more time than we'd wish.

Comment: "On a tangential note, what is with people copying and pasting close reason descriptions into the comments? That’s just noise. Vote to close, and move on. Don’t give people more mess to clean up." While it annoys me a ton too, I expect the reason is because (barring duplicates) the author doesn't see that information until the question is closed.  It'd be nice if the author was better information about the information in the close reason before the question is closed, similarly to how it's done for duplicates (where an altered message is shown indicating a possible problem.)

Comment: "On a tangential note, what is with people copying and pasting close reason descriptions into the comments? That’s just noise. Vote to close, and move on." Since the CV queue is just short of 8K entries it might take a while, if ever, before a post is closed. So the message being conveyed as you suggest might not ever be the case. In that there is value in posting such a message.

Comment: On the line of the prior commenters here, I do copy paste close reasons very rarely,  *because* SOs "be friendly" policy. Whenever I see a new user post something off-topic, yet fixable, I do inform them why their question may be closed so they can edit it in time. Because I am trying to be friendly to newbies. Most of the times I have been thanked for the explanation. Are you saying I should not do it? I am happy to stop, genuinely.

Comment: That is so weird.  I wish people would comment on each of their downvotes for my posts.  Otherwise, how do I improve?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I don't think that has anything to do with "be friendly". It's not unfriendly to use a copy/pasted message. It may not be helpful if the message isn't specific enough to the question, but that's a different thing from being unfriendly. Unhelpful doesn't mean unfriendly, you should take care to distinguish the two.

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude SO has been pivoting from "helpful and critical" to "nice and welcoming" for some time here, which is why Cody was bending over backwards to say that posting an idownvotedbecau.se link isn't unkind. Hopefully people listen to you because I agree, close reasons are good and I like idownvotedbecause because it provides an easy template for the most common reasons why questions are unanswerable.

Comment: I never got this sentiment - it's very easy too actually give feedback to authors. Rather than saying "I downvoted you because you didn't include an [mcve] or use the debugger" you can say "I would be frustrated if I had to debug this without first making an [mcve] and working without the debugger sounds hard. Have you considered that?". It's not that people don't like help on how to improve - they just don't like being talked down to...

Answer (score 9):

It's appropriate to flag such comments *that don't show help effort.*

These links are an extremely succinct way to show everything that needs to be fixed for the question to become answerable, and most of the time, there's nothing that needs adding.<sup>1</sup> If you get such a comment removed, the question won't magically become answerable, the OP will just lose information on what they need to do.

So the only way to judge if such a comment was thought out seems to be:

- Whether the question really exhibits all the pointed issues
- Whether all the pointed issues really are equally relevant, or some imply the others or something so the list could be reduced to 1-2 most relevant ones without any loss of value. Many instructions at once are likely to overwhelm, so I guess as a rule, 3 links are suspicious and 4 or more are a red flag.

Still heed the above-mentioned result of the removal and make a judgement call if it really is more trouble than it's worth.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I mean, "I could always add some question-specific specification if I feel like it but the articles really have all the info the OP needs."</sub>

Comment: Oh yes, good point. I like that metric - "if I get rid of this comment, can I say something at least as useful for the OP?". In this case, at least one or two of the reasons didn't really apply - one of them was nomcve even though there was (an attempt at) one in the question, which was why I went with 'no longer needed' originally. Plus the post was quite clearly headed for closure and was basically garbage anyway, so it's a bit moot, but it made me wonder.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave "if I get rid of this comment, can I say something at least as useful for the OP?" is not the metric in the answer. The metric is whether the comment provided any useful information. Comments do not have a link-only restriction. Do not encourage low effort users by doing the work of explaining every last detail of the problem with their question to them. They need to learn to do their own homework when asking questions, and reading the `idownvotedbecau.se` link is good training for them.

Comment: @jpmc26 - I don't think what you're saying contradicts my point (although your elaboration definitely makes sense). What I was trying to say is that if something useful is being removed, then something (similarly or more) useful should remain, for some definition of "useful". For a lot of cases the most "useful" resource might well be something from `idownvotedbecau.se`, but inevitably adding a few extra words will make something not-so-friendly (but not necessarily unfriendly) look a bit more welcoming, with little effort.

Comment: As a more concrete example, I'd be inclined to highlight the most egregious one or two issues, with a "you might like to read more here: idownvotedbecau.se/...". Putting myself in the shoes of someone receiving that comment, I think it would make me significantly more likely to read the big, possibly-intimidating explanation, than an easily-ignorable bare link. Although I absolutely take your point about learning to do their own homework w.r.t. finding out how to get help.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Being welcoming to people who are not interested in adapting to our culture of high quality content and doing your research before asking is counter productive.

Comment: @jpmc26 - I agree, but from a single poorly-asked question, I'd say it's hard to identify that their intent is not to adapt, in just the same way that it's hard to tell whether the intent behind a bare idownvotedbecau.se link is to helpfully inform or to snarkily offend. I'm sure the vast majority fall into the former category, but I've definitely seen people take advice on board and edit their questions appropriately. It's not hard to imagine that those people could go on to be very valuable members of the community.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave How they respond to an idownvotebecau.se link would actually be a good indicator of the author's willingness to adapt to SO's culture.

Answer (score -3):

As someone who did this previously, I'd say it completely depends on the context. 
For instance, I commented it here:

[Remove elements with same data-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56152503/remove-elements-with-same-data-id#comment98934432_56152503)

The OP did not provide any attempt whatsoever and the link I provided is pretty self-explanatory. According to the upvotes the comment got, and the downvotes the question received, it was appropriate I guess.

I provided the link only, because every necessary information is there. It didn't need any further explanation from me.

However, let's take "unclear what you're asking" as example. If it isn't clear what OP is asking, I wouldn't just leave a comment linking to [idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion), because I'd explain why we need more information and on what subject. This is handled on a case-by-case basis, unlike "no attempt" which is pretty much the same all the time.

Comment: And you where not able to add a better explanation like the person who commented after you? The link won't do a lot of good if they are on a very restrictive system and can't get to that domain.