# Are external URLs explaining a command not allowed?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

Some user just posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74849279/bash-script-expression-clarity-needed) about a Bash command, asking for clarity.

The question was quite broad, so I've casted a vote close and commented a link to https://explainshell.com/, with OP's command included: [link](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=printf%20%22%25.3f%22%20%24%28echo%20%24x%20%7C%20bc%20-l%29).

This was purely with the intention to give OP some info about this command.

---

A few minutes later, this comment was removed?

Since the [Bash Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) mentiones this as a Tool as:

> https://explainshell.com/ can pick apart many command lines and explain what the elements mean
> (notice that you can sometimes click on a result to have it picked apart further)

---

#### **Question:**

Are links like this not allowed, or should I have added more info?

Comment: I can see no reason to disallow such links; I frequently post comments with links to shellcheck.net for similar reasons. My comments usually go along the lines of "your script contains several common beginner errors; please try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance".

Comment: Was it short and “thank you”? Maybe someone clicked NLN?

Comment: @JamesRisner, yea the comment was [just the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LlCx.png), nothing else.,

Comment: I think a mod can tell if it got sent to mod  queue or if it was deleted by the 3 people flag it  poofs rule

Comment: If it was just the link, and no text explaining why one should follow the link, it's far more likely to get deleted.

Comment: Related / similar: [How should bare idownvotedbecau.se links in comments be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385088/how-should-bare-idownvotedbecau-se-links-in-comments-be-flagged)

Comment: The comment doesn't appear removed to me.

Answer (score 11):

Quoting from the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer.

The help section actually has some more guidance on usage of comments:

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Evaluate whether your link-only comment falls into any of the above categories.

- It did not request clarification from the author.
- It was not criticism/guidance on improving the post.
- You could say that it was transient information, but in this case how long should it stay up?

---

Some people consider link-only comments to be unfriendly. Maybe the commenter tried to be helpful, but it's not how it is perceived by readers. A link without an explanation is just redirecting readers off site with no explanation. Unless you know the site, you may wonder if it is even safe to open the link. It's like someone asking for directions to a place and you just telling them to use Google/Apple maps on their phone.

Comments like these are disliked also for another reason: you are shrugging the question off. We collect questions so a link to some automated tool that provides an explanation of how code works is not helpful to the site.

---

In conclusion, don't add link-only comments. If you think the link adds some information to the topic, explain why should someone visit the link and what they can find there. But an even better place for links to helpful tools would be in the tag wiki. If someone is keen on finding tools like this they will read the tag wiki.

Answer (score 7):

I can't speak for the mod who deleted this, but there was an "unfriendly" flag on it.

Why would a mere link be deleted like that? We get a lot of folks who browbeat others with links. Stuff that implies

- You didn't Google this (which we [actively discourage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397/lmgtfy-link-cant-be-added))
- Here's the first link in Google
- Here's an article I know of. Just go read that

We delete a lot of comments **at scale**. I mean, [we deleted 403k comments last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415250/2021-a-year-in-moderation). And comments [are never meant to be permanent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312002/244695). Our standards of removal are, thus, much lower (and it takes more than one "unfriendly" flag for a mod to be notified for comment review).

So... I don't think you were trying to be rude here. I think it was taken as that last one ("Go read this"). To that end, I've undeleted it. We don't have any rule about linking articles, but be aware we can, and do, remove bare link comments without warning.

Answer (score 6):

As the mod that deleted the comment - in response to the flags - I certainly interpreted it as more like one of the first two points in [Machavity's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422233).

However, if I'd seen the comment "in the wild" I probably wouldn't have given it a second thought. It was simply the fact that someone had been bothered enough by the comment to flag it for our attention.

As Machavity said we have a much lower threshold for deleting comments than deleting answers or questions so something like this will be more likely to get deleted if it's flagged than the same sort of content in an answer - assuming that the answer is an answer of course.

Answer (score 1):

### Consider the question first

If the question deserves an answer, then offer an answer in the answer section. It is not a problem that a question can be asked briefly and answered briefly - as long as it is clear, focused, not a duplicate etc. Please refrain from link-only answers; excerpt the appropriate information from the target of the link (with appropriate attribution) and explain - in complete English sentences - how it applies to the situation described in the question.

If the question should not be answered as it stands, then **the only good reason to provide an informational link is to demonstrate the issue with the question**.

#### In this case

In the particular case of this post, a specific, focused question was asked (or at least implied):

> I am not able to understand the use-case of "-l" after bc.

As such, a link to a service that parses the entire command **does not address the question**. When I try the link that you've offered, I find that in order to answer OP's question, I have to click through on the nested command ( `echo(1) $x | bc(1) -l`), then scroll to the bottom, where I am simply given a citation from the man page -

```
-l, --mathlib
       Define the standard math library.
```

This probably does not clarify things very much for someone who would post such a question.

As asked, the question is a duplicate, and properly closed as such. It is a poor signpost (the title does not highlight was is being asked; and the body of the post is written in [noisy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721), discussion-forum mode that doesn't make the question explicit), and as such should probably be deleted (I cast a delete vote after making this assessment). But posting a link like yours is not productive in this context. It comes across as scolding OP for a lack of effort, whereas the only effort required here is in research - which should, ideally, have found the canonical. (The duplicate linked here doesn't seem to be particularly canonical; if there isn't a better canonical, then it should be improved and reopened - if there is, it should be hammered as well.)

#### But hypothetically...

If the question **weren't** like that - if the question were simply "I have a command `printf "%.3f" $(echo $x | bc -l)`; what does it do?", then that would be closable (and, hopefully, quickly closed) as Needs More Focus. In this case, it's useful to comment to explain that questions like this need [research in order to establish focus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) (and lack of an existing duplicate).

A link like yours is helpful, in that it highlights a useful resource for that kind of research, while also pointing out the *kind of analysis* that can be done in order to focus the question. Someone who puts a command like this into a service like explainshell.com, and still has a question, will now have an **appropriate** question - such as "what impact does 'defining the standard math library' have when using `bc`?".

It is still appropriate, however, to comment more than just the link. The polite, **courteous** thing to do - rather than leave your meaning implied by the link itself - is to

- welcome new users;
- explain what is expected of questions here;
- explain what is wrong with the question as asked;
- show how services like this can be helpful.

In this hypothetical, I might have drafted the comment like so (and split it across multiple comments if necessary):

> Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) the question to be *focused and specific*. Questions simply asking to explain a code excerpt (such as a shell command) are [not appropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894) here. Instead, first try to figure out exactly *what part* of the code confuses you, and *what confusion* you have about it. There are online services that [can help with this task](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo+%24x+%7C+bc+-l).