# Hang tight, [serp]'s up

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[serp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serp) 84 questions

> Serp refers to Search Engine Results Page. This page displays the results of search query. General questions about SEO are off topic here unless directly related to programming.

The results are not good

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Not always. Sometimes the questions are about SERPs, sometimes, how to [manipulate them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694262/php-dont-output-date-if-user-agent-is-a-search-engine-crawler)

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

The problem with this tag is that it is often used for [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo) purposes. Most of the on-topic questions are about [web-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping). As [general SEO is off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618/2370483), most of the questions are off-topic, most often the answer is **NO**.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Somewhat. They all involve something about search engine results.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Not in general. Sometimes about [ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228071/what-is-google-search-result-page-carousel-technologies), sometimes about [scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995284/serp-tracker-php-script-dontwork), sometimes [search meta data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580616/google-authorship-not-working). They're in the same wheelhouse, but not the same thing.

Comment: I seeded the close vote queue with some of the worse questions if anyone would like to filter on this.

Comment: Isn't *serp* a short form of *serpent*? `:)`

Comment: Concerning the unclear name of the tag there may be room for improvement, but whatsoever I **still see a purpose for this tag** : how to make your content appear in specific ways on SERPs. Google for example supports "structured data" : https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data

Comment: @LMD Er, no. We have specific tags for those. [tag:schema.org] and [tag:json-ld]. Furthermore, [only 3 questions in the tag are related](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bserp%5D+schema+is%3Aq&mixed=0)

Comment: Ah, so synonymize with [[tag:python]] then, @iBug?

Comment: I always thought the term was *hang ten*

Comment: SERPs were a popular investment vehicle for pension funds in the UK a while ago (Supplemental Employee Retirement Plan). Perhaps due to the ambiguity the tag should be 'retired'. Drum roll

Comment: Maybe you should tell people to hang loose instead.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I agree with this request. This tag isn't really about programming; it actively draws off-topic questions, and should be removed.

Please, stop this tag from being further abused.